# Removing row to minus sum of cart giving negative result

Tags: android, android-adapter

I have a Shopping cart that gets all the rows and sums it up in a textView, I have been able to do that. And I have buttons on each item so that when removed it will minus it from the total amount before.

I have been able to get the results, but somehow it gives me negative results.

Can anyone help me here? Thanks in advance :D

This is the adapter class:

```
//BUTTON TO REMOVE ROW
   btnRemove.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                    .setTitle("REMOVE" + " " + orderName.get(position) + " " + "FROM CART?")
                    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                            db.removeSingleContact(orderid.get(position));
                            orderName.remove(position);
                            orderSize.remove(position);
                            orderQuantity.remove(position);
                            orderTotal.remove(position);
                            notifyDataSetChanged();

                            db.close();

                           //And this is the function that minuses the sum of the text, but gives a negative answer
                            Double totals = 0.00;
                            for(String s : orderTotal){
                                totals -= Double.parseDouble(s);
                            }


                                //I have called the method that would change the textTotal from the other class
                                ((cart)context).updateTotal(String.valueOf(totals));

                        }
                    })
```

This is my MainActivity class:

```
   //And this is the method I call in the adapter class to minus the total when the btnRemove is clicked

   public void updateTotal(String amount)
{
    textTotal.setText(amount);
}
```

Comment: Use totals += Double.parseDouble(s);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already `removed` the position from `orderTotal`. To get `totals` use `totals += Double.parseDouble(s)`.

**Use:**

```
Double totals = 0.00;
for(String s : orderTotal) {
    totals += Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

**Instead of:**

```
Double totals = 0.00;
for(String s : orderTotal) {
    totals -= Double.parseDouble(s);
}
```

Comment: Sir I cannot believe I did not even changed it back to plus and try it hahaha.. But thank you anyways for the help sir, I really appreciate it! :D